# Delete files with python through OS shell

Tags: python, file

Im Tyring to Delete all Files in E:.
with wildcard.

```
E:\test\*.txt
```

I would ask rather than test the os.walk. 
In windows.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A slightly verbose writing of another method

```
import os
dir = "E:\\test"
files = os.listdir(dir)
for file in files:
    if file.endswith(".txt"):
        os.remove(os.path.join(dir,file))
```

Or

```
import os
[os.remove(os.path.join("E:\\test",f)) for f in os.listdir("E:\\test") if f.endswith(".txt")]
```

Comment: I'd rather write: map(os.remove, [os.path.join("E:\\test",f)) for f in os.listdir("E:\\test") if f.endswith(".txt")])

Comment: beautiful solution, woks amazingly and is cross-platform.

Comment: @AnthonyPerot Why is the use of `map` better than the list comprehension mentioned in the answer?

Answer (score 58):

The way you would do this is use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module:

```
import glob
import os
for fl in glob.glob("E:\\test\\*.txt"):
    #Do what you want with the file
    os.remove(fl)
```

Comment: I just ran it on my machine and it worked fine. Are you sure you have permission to remove those files? What happens if you do the following on the command promt: E: <br />cd test <br />del [filename]?

Comment: Obviously replace "[filename]" with the name of a file.

Comment: OS= windows, permission: yes "E: <br />cd test <br />del [filename]" on windows??

Comment: Is there a reason using the glob module is the method preferred over the accepted answer? (Going by votes on answer)
What advantages does it have over the other answer?

Comment: @AaronAlphonsus It let you use the `*` instead of `if file.endswith(".txt"):` in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use popen for this as well if you want to do it in fewer lines

```
from subprocess import Popen
proc = Popen("del E:\test\*.txt",shell=False)
```

Comment: Best to use Python libraries as it makes your code cross-platform, is less brittle and gives rich exceptions. If brevity is important, you achieve the same in one line using Python native libs with: `#import glob,os ; [os.remove(x) for x in glob.glob("E:\test\*.txt")]`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete file with more than one extension then define those extensions in tuple like below

```
import os

def purge(dir):
    files = os.listdir(dir)
    ext = ('.txt', '.xml', '.json')
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            print("File -> " + os.path.join(dir,file))
            os.remove(os.path.join(dir,file))
```