# Calling rm from subprocess using wildcards does not remove the files

Tags: python, django, shell, rm

I'm trying to build a function that will remove all the files that start with 'prepend' from the root of my project. Here's what I have so far

```
def cleanup(prepend):
    prepend = str(prepend)
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    end = "%s*" % prepend
    cmd = 'rm'
    args = "%s/%s" % (PROJECT_ROOT, end)
    print "full cmd = %s %s" %(cmd, args)
    try:
        p = Popen([cmd, args],  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True).communicate()[0]
        print "p", p
    except Exception as e:
        print str(e)
```

I'm not having any luck -- it doesn't seem to be doing anything. Do you have any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: I think Levon's answer is the better approach; that said, if you want to see what this is doing, run this under `strace(1)` with `-f` command line option and you can see the exact `execve(2)` system call that is being made.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The problem is that you are passing two arguments to `subprocess.Popen`: `rm` and a path, such as `/home/user/t*` (if the prefix is `t`). `Popen` then will try to remove a file named *exactly this way*: t followed by an asterisk at the end.

If you want to use `Popen` with the wildcard, you should pass the `shell` parameter as `True`. In this case, however, the command should be a string, not a list of arguments:

```
Popen("%s %s" % (cmd, args), shell=True, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, close_fds=True)
```

(Otherwise, [the list of arguments will be given to the new shell, not to the command](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor))

Another solution, safer and more efficient, is to use [the `glob` module](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html):

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(prepend+"*")
args = [cmd] + files
Popen(args,  stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

However, I agree that Levon's solution is the saner one. In this case, `glob` is the answer too:

```
files = glob.glob(prepend+"*")
for file in files:
    os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 18):

Would you consider this approach using [os.remove()](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os.remove#os.remove) to deleting files instead of `rm`:

```
import os
os.remove('Path/To/filename.ext')
```

**Update** (basically moving my comment from below into my answer)**:**

As `os.remove()` can't handle wildcards on its own, using the [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to help will yield a solution as repeated verbatim from this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5532521/1209279):

```
import glob
import os
for fl in glob.glob("E:\\test\\*.txt"):
    #Do what you want with the file
    os.remove(fl)
```

Comment: Definitely! Can I use wildcards in the remove call?

Comment: `os.remove()` by itself can't handle wildcards, but this SO answer shows some code using `os.remove()` with the `glob` module to do just this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5532521/1209279 .. there are other approaches also shown.

Comment: @mythander889 No -- wildcards are evaluated by the shell, and the best ways of doing this (from a security perspective) have no shell involved. `import glob, os; for filename in glob.glob('*.txt'): os.remove(filename)`

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (which also works on Windows, though I'm guessing that's not a concern for you:

```
def cleanup(prepend):
    prepend = str(prepend)
    PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    for file_to_delete in [file for file in os.listdir(PROJECT_ROOT) if file.startswith(prepend)]:
        os.remove(file_to_delete)
```