# How to use the mv command in Python with subprocess

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, stat, mv

I have a lot of files in /home/somedir/subdir/ and I'm trying to move them all up to /home/somedir programmatically.

right now I have this:

```
subprocess.call(["mv", "/home/somedir/subdir/*", "somedir/"])
```

but it's giving me this error:

```
mv: cannot stat `/home/somedir/subdir/*': No such file or directory
```

I know that it does exist because when I type the mv command by hand using the exact same command as the script uses it works perfectly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling rm from subprocess using wildcards does not remove the files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025784/calling-rm-from-subprocess-using-wildcards-does-not-remove-the-files)

Comment: it's close, but imho not a duplicate, as the other is using `Popen` and has a more complex example.

Comment: Well, the problem and solution idea are very close. I've already seen some close votes less obvious than that...

Comment: I think it is a dup—it's the same actual problem, with the same actual solution. This question serves as a much better example of the problem, but that doesn't mean it's a different problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

if you call subprocess that way:

```
subprocess.call(["mv", "/home/somedir/subdir/*", "somedir/"])
```

you're actually giving the argument `/home/somedir/subdir/*` to the `mv` command, with an actual `*` file. i.e. you're actually trying to move the `*` file.

```
subprocess.call("mv /home/somedir/subdir/* somedir/", shell=True)
```

it will use the shell that will expand the first argument.

*Nota Bene*: when using the `shell=True` argument you need to change your argument list into a string that will be given to the shell.

*Hint*: You can also use the `os.rename()` or `shutil.move()` functions, along with `os.path.walk()` or `os.listdir()` to move the files to destination in a more pythonic way.

Comment: +2 For Pythonic idiom; otherwise, one may as well use the shell!

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this by adding the parameter `shell=True`, to take into account wildcards in your case (and so write the command directly, without any list):

```
subprocess.call("mv /home/somedir/subdir/* somedir/", shell=True)
```

Without it, the argument is directly given to the `mv` command with the asterisk. It's the shell job to return every files which match the pattern in general.

Answer (score 2):

You are using shell globbing `*`, and expecting the `mv` command to know what it means. You can get the same error from a command shell this way:

`$ mv 'somedir/subdir/*' ...`

Notice the quotes. The shell usually does glob-matching on `*` for you, but commands don't do that on their command lines; not even a shell does. There is a C library function called `fnmatch` that does shell-style globbing for you, which every programming language more or less copies. It might even have the same name in Python. Or it might have the word "glob" in it; I don't remember.

Comment: your example does actually work the shell expands inside double quotes, you should use single quotes to make a point.

Comment: Oh, that's right. What's really fun is the way (ba)sh handles single quotes inside of double quotes. It can get pretty hairy when you stash it in a var and then try to splice it into a command line!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way to work with subprocess Popen

```py
import subprocess
import os

class FolderCommands:
    src = None
    dst = None

    def __init__(self, src, dst):
        self.src = src
        self.dst = dst

    def move(self):
        listOfFiles = os.listdir(self.src)
        print(listOfFiles)
        modify_src = self.src.replace(" ", "\ ")
        dst = self.dst.replace(" ", "\ ")
        for f in listOfFiles:
            #Attaching the filename at the end of the src path

            fullPath = modify_src + "/'" + f +"'"
            subprocess.Popen("mv" + " " + fullPath + " " + dst, shell=True)

obj = FolderCommands(input("Enter Source path"), input("Enter Destination path"))
obj.move()
```

Comment: While this does escape blanks, there are other characters of concern.  Tabs, newlines, and single quotes are all valid characters in filenames and would need special attention.