# Python: subprocess call doesn't recognize * wildcard character?

Tags: python, linux, shell, subprocess

I want to remove all the `*.ts` in file. But `os.remove` didn't work.

```
>>> args = ['rm', '*.ts']
>>> p = subprocess.call(args)
rm: *.ts No such file or directory
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling rm from subprocess using wildcards does not remove the files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11025784/calling-rm-from-subprocess-using-wildcards-does-not-remove-the-files)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `rm` program takes a list of filenames, but `*.ts` isn't a list of filenames, it's a pattern for matching filenames.  You have to name the actual files for `rm`.  When you use a shell, the shell (but not `rm`!) will expand patterns like `*.ts` for you.  In Python, you have to explicitly ask for it.

```
import glob
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(['rm', '--'] + glob.glob('*.ts'))
#                            ^^^^ this makes things much safer, by the way
```

Of course, why bother with `subprocess`?

```
import glob
import os
for path in glob.glob('*.ts'):
    os.remove(path)
```

Comment: What does "this" make much safer and why?

Comment: The `--` parameter separates flags like `-f` from filenames. If you have a file named `-f`, then you can remove it using `rm -- -f`, but you cannot remove it using `rm -f`, because it is interpreted as a flag.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Though I'd argue if someone accidentally deletes a file they called `-f` they probably had it coming.

Comment: The problem sometimes comes up because people allow users to choose filenames, and then somebody else (besides the user who created the file) goes in to do some administrative work.