# Deleting files using wildcards with python glob module

Tags: python, glob

Was looking for a method to delete files using a wildcard. Came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532498/delete-files-with-python-through-os-shell?answertab=oldest#tab-top) which helped me out. I thought the accepted answer was easier to understand and that's the method I would prefer.

However, it looks like the answer which utilizes the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module is considerably more popular. What are the possible reasons for this? Is there an advantage that this method has over the accepted answer?

Comment: I would have posted a comment on the answer but 1. I don't have the reputation required and 2. It seemed more like a question

Comment: The asker appears to have had some issues getting `glob` to work, so did not accept it.

Comment: Yes, I see that, but I guess I was trying to point out the difference in upvotes received by the two answers as an indicator of the more popular answer.

Answer (score 0):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

The one obvious way to find all path names that match a pattern is the glob module, since that is [what it is documented to do](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html).

The accepted answer implements a subset of glob's functionality, it can find all files ending in `.txt`. It is not wrong, but it is not the One Way.